# How to merge and duplicate two arrays and list in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two object arrays:

```
const arr1 = [
{groupId: 1, name: 'group1'}, 
{groupId: 2, name: 'group2'}
]
const arr2 = [
{groupId: 1, itemId: 1, name: 'item1'}, 
{groupId: 1, itemId: 2, name: 'item2'}, 
{groupId: 1, itemId: 3, name: 'item3'}
]
```

I want output to be list like this in react.js

```
 1. group1
    1.1 item1
    1.2 item2
    1.3 item3
 2. group2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: React.js is just JavaScript (or JSX if you're being pedantic). Have you tried doing this with regular JavaScript? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: yes, I tried to do it. I used concat function but it didn't what I want.

Comment: Please share your code so we can debug where you went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer below can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const arr1 = [
{groupId: 1, name: 'group1'}, 
{groupId: 2, name: 'group2'}
]
const arr2 = [
{groupId: 1, itemId: 1, name: 'item1'}, 
{groupId: 1, itemId: 2, name: 'item2'}, 
{groupId: 1, itemId: 3, name: 'item3'}
]

//in render function
arr1.map(arr => (
    <ListHeader title={arr.name}>
        {arr2.map(a => (
            a.groupId === arr.groupId ? <ListItem title={a.name} /> : null
        )}
    </ListHeader>    
))
```